# PHP retrieve previous value after form submision inside loop

Tags: php, cookies, input

How can I **retrieve selected** value after form submision inside *looped* `HTML` select? I managed to solve the problem with manual if statements, but thats not dynamic.
I'm also storing previously submited value inside a `cookie`. *I use self page form submit.*

I managed to retrieve previous value from radio button:

```
  <input type="radio" name="spol" value="moški" checked="checked" <?php if (isset($_POST['spol']) && $_POST['spol'] == 'moški') {
            echo ' checked="checked"';
        } ?>>
```

But can't find a way to do this inside `foreach` loop

```
<!---Cookie "keks" is storing previous submited string-->
     <select name="status">
                <?php
                $_COOKIE['keks'];
                $statusi = ["Dijak", "Študent", "Zaposlen", "Brezposelni"];
                $counter= 0;
                foreach ($statusi as $status) {
                    $counter++;
                     if ($counter == 2) {
                       echo "<option  value=" . $status . " selected>" . $status . "</option>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value=" . $status . ">" . $status . "</option>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </select>
```

Comment: please don't add the blockquote back in. I am not up to an edit war today.

Comment: So first things first, why does your first radio (potentially) have *two* `checked="checked"`? And what is `$_COOKIE['keks'];` supposed to do? There seem to be many strange things in this sample...

Comment: `if ($stevec == 2)` where is that defined?

Comment: On the page I have multiple radio buttons. This is the first one and it have to be already checked.

Comment: @Jeto this is an implementation of double click

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I forgot to translate that. This is defined as `$counter`.

Comment: @Cid I'll just assume this is sarcasm :)

Comment: @Jeto more a joke than a sarcasm :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in html comment, `$_COOKIE['keks'];` is storing the last value.

You might want to store that value into a variable or use it as is. and then, compare it against the current iteration of your loop.

```
$lastValue = $_COOKIE['keks'];
// some code
foreach ($statusi as $status)
{
    if ($status == $lastValue)
        // mark the option as selected
    else
        // don't mark it
}
```

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for!